# Get values from Table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In my following code, I browse a table and look for columns containing blue icon if it is the case , I count number of lines having blue icon and containing word "ble" 
but what I have do doesn't' work as I like.

```
for (int i = 0; i <myTable.getRowCount(); i++)
     {
       myTable.selectCell(i, 1);
       if (myTable.getIcon(i, 0) == ("blue.gif"))
       {

        if (myTable.getRowValue(i, 0).contains("ble."))
        {
         int counter = 0;
         counter = counter + 1;
         System.out.println(counter);

        }

     }
}
```

Comment: there are three areas, 1) how ways you put `Icon/ImageIcon` to `TableCell` 2) how you defined `Column#Class` for paticular `TableColumn` 3) type of `TableModel` and `TableCellRenderer` if exist, *** check for those topics on this forum, or edit your post with runnable code that shows all workaround for your `JTable`, or start a new Thread with Topic `How to put Icon/ImageIcon` to the `JTable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `counter` variable must be declared above the `for`:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <myTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
    myTable.selectCell(i, 1);
    if (myTable.getIcon(i, 0) == ("blue.gif")) {
        if (myTable.getRowValue(i, 0).contains("ble.")) {
           counter++;
           System.out.println(counter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alexey, I tried what you suggest but in the console I do not have a print of counter :(

Comment: This code is identical to yours with `counter` declared before `for` loop as others pointed. I guess you have to compare icons in some other way, or there's a class name missing before parenthesis in `("blue.gif")`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you reset the counter to 0 before you add 1 to it, so the counter always displays 1.

Answer (score 0):

Does not work as I like means you get all 1s, I assume? This is because you reset the counter inside your if every time:

```
for (...) {
    ...
    if (...) {
        int counter = 0; // you do this every time
    }
    ...
}
```

Instead, move the counter out of the loop:

```
int counter = 0; // only do it once, here
for (...) {
    ...
    if (...) {
        counter = counter + 1
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Seeing as you're already using 'i' as your counter variable there's no need to make another one called 'counter'.

```
   for (int i = 0; i <myTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
        myTable.selectCell(i, 1);
        if (myTable.getIcon(i, 0) == ("blue.gif")) {
            if (myTable.getRowValue(i, 0).contains("ble.")) {
               System.out.println(i + "");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `i` is the iterator through all the rows of the table. `counter` variable is used to get the number of rows which meet the conditions.